# Only show order when all the order detail are received

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables an `OrderHeader` and `OrderDetail` Table. What I need to do is Check the `StatusFK` in the `Detail` table for each record that relate to the `OrderHeader` Table.

So if all related records in the `StatusFK = 2` in the `Detail` table then I want this to show in the query as I will run an update on the `OrderHeader` Record to change its `Status` to received.

But say there are 6 records in the detail table that relate to the `OrderHeader` table, but only 5 out of 6 have `StatusFK = 2`, then I do not want this to show as it is not ready to be classed as fully received?

I hope somebody can make sense of what I'm saying and hopefully help me achieve this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you only want OrderHeaders where the count of order detail records equals the count of the OrderDetails that have the statusFK of 2.

You can do that by using a SUM/IIF and compare it to the detail record count in the HAVING clause

```
SELECT OrderHeader.OrderID, OrderHeader.Name
FROM OrderHeader 
     INNER JOIN OrderDetail
     ON OrderHeader.OrderId = OrderDetail.OrderId
GROUP BY OrderHeader.OrderID, OrderHeader.Name
HAVING 
      Count(OrderDetail.OrderId )   = SUM(IiF (OrderDetail.StatusFK = 2 ,1,0) )
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, the trick would be to query in LEFT JOIN against the order detail where the status is not received, and test that no row exists for a unwanted status.

Not knowing your version of MS Access, I can't garantee the exact syntax, but a query similar to the following should do the trick.

```
SELECT OrderHeader.*, OrderDetail.* FROM OrderDetail
JOIN OrderHeader ON HeaderFK = HeaderID
LEFT JOIN OrderDetail AS OrderDetailNotReceived ON OrderDetailNotReceived.HeaderFK = HeaderID AND OrderDetailNotReceived.StatusFK < 2
WHERE OrderDetailNotReceived.DetailID IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help this is my completed query and looks like it is doing the trick, i just need to incorporate it into my Update query

```
SELECT tblOrder.OrderPK
  FROM tblOrder 
   INNER JOIN tblOrderDetail
    ON tblOrder.OrderPK = tblOrderDetail.OrderFK
GROUP BY tblOrder.OrderPK
  HAVING 
   Count(tblOrderDetail.OrderFK )   = SUM(IiF (tblOrderDetail.StatusFK = 2 ,1,0) )
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just realized that my above query, is readonly as it contains Totals, i need to be able to link it into an update able query?

is there an easy way to get around this?

thanks